# nodejs-legacy does not install

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

i am trying to install nodejs-legacy in ubuntu but it gives errors.please help.
i also have removed all those traces left behind by nodejs from all sources
in the local system.i have also done:
sudo apt-get install autoclean
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy

doesnot work

please suggest

```html
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs-legacy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 122 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe nodejs-legacy all 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 [14.6 kB]
Fetched 14.6 kB in 0s (18.4 kB/s)      
(Reading database ... 261633 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs-legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs-legacy (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz', which is also in package nodejs 0.10.37-1chl1~trusty1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
manish@manish-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:/var/cache/apt/archives$ whereis nodejs
nodejs:
manish@manish-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:/var/cache/apt/archives$ which nodejs
manish@manish-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:/var/cache/apt/archives$
```

Comment: looks like you have package `nodejs` still installed which is conflicting.

Answer (score 2):

sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb

Comment: I guess running forcefully is the only option that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, by forcefully OverWriting these commands.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs-legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an installed package `nodejs`, that has some file which overlaps with the `node-legacy` package.

Have you tried to uninstall the `nodejs` package first?

Comment: yes i removed every thing from every sources ,hand picked :P

Comment: I'm getting this on a fresh system, trying to install `npm` which requires both `nodejs` and `node-legacy`.